# How to report that a question should be migrated to another site?

Tags: support, migration, reporting

How do I report that a question should be moved to a different site (from stackoverflow.com to superuser.com, in example)?

Comment: The relevant info has been edited into the FAQ, so this is now a duplicate. Please note that it's policy to close questions as duplicates of FAQs even if they're merely related, and even if the information wasn't contained in the FAQ at the time the question was asked. This is to direct all users to the canonical source containing the relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have less than 3000 reputation, then the traditionally effective means is actually to do nothing. The people who can vote to migrate are quite active, these kinds of questions tend to be picked up very fast, and they don't need any flagging to do that job.

You can consider posting a comment saying "This should be posted at [other site]". But be careful! You might convince the poster to do that, but the original post may still be migrated, and there will now be duplication! This is actually why not saying anything tends to be more effective.

If you really are worried about it, you can flag it for moderator attention explaining which site it belong on. I really don't recommend this because it should only be used for drastic measures, and migration rarely is such. But it's always an option if you feel it is necessary.

Of course, with over 3000 reputation, simply cast a vote-to-close to migrate it. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Does this answer still apply? Sub-3000 users can specifically flag as "belongs on xyz site"; is that not good for some reason?

Answer (score 5):

Users with more than 3000 reputation can vote to migrate any question. Users with more than 250 reputation can vote to migrate their own questions. It's actually a close vote, but the result is that the question is moved.

If you have less than 3000 points (or 250 it it's your own question) then you can do one of four things:

1. Leave a comment. This is not ideal as the poster might go off and post a new question on Super User and when the original question is migrated it creates a duplicate.
2. Flag the question for moderator attention, giving migration as the reason. This should only be used in exceptional circumstances.
3. Post a question here on meta with a link to the post and an explanation of why you think it should be migrated.
4. Leave it for other 3K+ users to spot and vote to close/migrate.

Option 4 is by far the easiest thing for you to do, unless you think that it's really urgent that the question is moved, in which case go for 3 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

Vote to close it as "Belongs on [Target Site]".

If you do not have sufficient rep to vote to close, just put a comment below the question that says "Belongs on [Target Site]", or do nothing at all.  Generally, there are enough high-rep users who will see the question, and vote it to the other site.

If you feel strongly about it, and the question has gone dead (i.e. people are not looking at it anymore), flag it for moderator attention, and put in the description, "Belongs on [Target Site]."

Comment: On my questions, how do I vote to close it? I see there is a link titled "close", but I take it closes the question directly. Is that correct, or the link allows to start the vote?

Comment: The link is to "vote to close."  Four more users must also click the link to close the question.

Comment: The problem I have with simply commenting: Belongs on ... is that some new users will duplicate the question on the target site, rather then letting the system do it's work...

Comment: @Ivo Also when the question is migrated the now unnecessary "Belongs on" comment is migrated with it

Answer (score 1):

In general if you feel very strongly something should be migrated...

- if you have 3k+ rep, vote to close it as appropriate
- if you do not, flag for moderator attention with a brief note where you want it to go, and why

Comment: Have you considered allowing original authors 'one click migration' as you give them 'one click deletion?' Often, a quick comment to the OP leads to them being more than happy to move, and think of all the close votes we could save to use on the bad stuff.