# How do I move a question to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, off-topic, vote-to-close

How do I move a question to another Stack Exchange site? For example, I see a lot of questions which are specific to WordPress, and should be asked in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

But when I mark them off-topic, I do not see how I can move it there. I see only five, probably the top five, Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Lots of similar questions on the "Related" tab over on the right-hand side. Here's one: [How to report that a question should be migrated to another site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/how-to-report-that-a-question-should-be-migrated-to-another-site)

Comment: ehhhh....if u read my question u will see that the answer u brought is exactly my problem. As the normal procedure does not solve it. I do have more than 3K on SO.

Comment: Read ChrisF's answer, Itay. You can flag posts for migration. Even if you have more than 3K rep.

Comment: OK...if I have a wordpress question in SO and I mark it as off topic, there is no way for me to mark it to be migrated to the WordPress Stack Exchange site. That lack of way is my problem. If there is a way, I missed it. It is not in the answer u suggested though.

Comment: Yes, there is. Flag it, with a custom moderator message.

Comment: Moderators are few, and flags are saved for more, shall we say, extreme problems. Otherwise they get flooded.

Comment: So, you're not looking for support. You're asking for a new feature.  FWIW, others have asked for it before you - it's been declined.

Comment: in the begining I was looking how to do it, u showed me the only available ways there are. Only then it changed to new feature request, which u said is rejected (why b.t.w?)

Comment: If you're now making a feature request, you should rewrite your question as such, and tag it `[feature-request]`. [Here's a declined request for the same feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/96345).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target site is not in the list of possible migrations (what we call a site's migration path), the thing to do is flag the post for moderator attention, select 'other' and indicate where you feel the question should go.

You indicated in comments that you'd rather not add unnecessary work for moderators. That's very polite of you, however that type of flag is very easy to service. If the moderator also feels that the question would be a better fit on another site, they'll migrate it.

If you're worried that perhaps a moderator won't see your flag in time to migrate a question before the community closes it as off topic, that's also not a big concern; if the question has been closed, but was good, a moderator will re-open and migrate it. Additionally, you can leave a comment indicating that you flagged for migration to let others know.

Migration paths are established when they'll be beneficial for both sides of the path. If the site you have in mind is not an established migration path, you'll have to involve a moderator.